# Calling action filter automatically in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

I'm trying to develop a plugin for nopcommerce and trying to catch model for a page (after submitted) in an action filter so that I can make some changes to model properties.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Data dt = new Data();

        dt.id = 54;
        dt.name = "something";
        return View(dt);
    }
```

and this is the fitler:

```
public class ModelChangerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            Data dt = new Data();
            dt = (Data) filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
            dt.id++;
            dt.name += " someotherthing";

            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["dt"] = dt;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

But for action filter to run I need to specify it before method in controller. And I'm not down with that.

don't want to do this:

```
        [ModelChangerAttribute]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ...
```

**So is it possible to call filter automatically each time a controller method is run?**

Please provide an example **HERE**.

Comment: You can apply it to the controller is you want it for all methods in it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't want to edit controller at ALL.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _edit the controller_? Its `[ModelChangerAttribute] public class yourController : Controller {` or register it globally to all controllers in `global.asax`

Comment: How do I register it globally? An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in App_Start/FilterConfig.cs:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ModelChangerAttribute());
    }
}
```

Additional info: you should call this in global.asax in Application_Start():

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

Comment: This runs for EVERY controller?